# struts tiles.xml directly refer jsp without template or layout

Tags: jsp, struts2, tiles, refer

I need to return a jsp as is in my Struts 2 application. The Struts application is setup with tiles. Some of the jsp's are already using tiles with a default template or layout. But for a new jsp, which will be embedded in a container, that I need to return as is, without any additional tag for header, body, footer, etc., inserted from `tiles.xml`. How can I do it?

I think there are two possible places that I can make the change:

1. in struts.xml, to directly say go to this jsp, instead of let tiles resolve the name
2. in tiles.xml, directly say go to this jsp, without template
   Anybody has done this before ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the question? Seems you know two possible solutions. Go with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a little. It looks like in `struts.xml`, we can have both flavor at the same time, one to refer `tiles.xml`, the other use a location `param`.

```
<result name="success">eventHistory</result> 
<result name="none" type="dispatcher">
    <param name="location">/EventHistoryBUIC.jsp</param>
</result>
```